# Converting column type 'datetime64[ns]' to datetime in Python3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like to perform a comparison between the two dates (One from a pandas dataframe) in python3, another one is calculated. I would like to filter pandas dataframe if the values in the 'Publication_date' is equal to or less than the today's date and is greater than the date 10 years ago.

The pandas df looks like this:

```
       PMID  Publication_date
0  31611796  2019-09-27
1  33348808  2020-12-17  
2  12089324  2002-06-27
3  31028872  2019-04-25
4  26805781  2016-01-21
```

I am doing the comparison as shown below.

```
df[(df['Publication_date']> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3650)) & 
                  (df['Publication_date']<= datetime.date.today())]
```

Above date filter when applied on the df should not give Row:3 of the df.

'Publication_date' column has type 'string'. I converted it to date using below line in my script.

```
df_phenotype['publication_date']= pd.to_datetime(df_phenotype['publication_date'])
```

But it changes the column  type to 'datetime64[ns]' that makes the comparison incompatible between 'datetime64[ns]' and datetime.

How can I perform this comparison?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only pandas for working with datetimes - [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) is for remove times from datetimes (set times to `00:00:00`):

```
df['Publication_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Publication_date'])

today = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
df1 = df[(df['Publication_date']> today - pd.Timedelta(days=3650)) & 
                  (df['Publication_date']<= today)]
```

Also you can use `10 years` offset:

```
today = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
df1 = df[(df['Publication_date']> today - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=10)) & 
                  (df['Publication_date']<= today)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
       PMID Publication_date
0  31611796       2019-09-27
1  33348808       2020-12-17
3  31028872       2019-04-25
4  26805781       2016-01-21
```

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: @rshar - It seems you forget `df['Publication_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Publication_date'])`